# Adblock or Facebook

Tags: facebook

There was an image on facebook that went with an article I wanted to post from Fox News, but because I didn't like the picture I did "Block Ad" on the picture, and it took it out. Now some of my other pictures are not showing up. Is that an Adblock issue or a Facebook issue?  how can I tell which is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Ad-blocking mechnisms and rules are generated by your plugin "Adblock" and it seems you added a general rule to block images within a specific code-region of a site. That means, all images (on Facebook and other sites) where this rule applies are being blocked.

If you dislike the image associated with a specific Facebook share, you shouldn't use Adblock, but Facebook's built-in feature: "No thumbnail"

[image: No thumbnail!]